# Python stemmer for Georgian

Tags: python, nlp, python-3.x, stemming

I am currently working with **Georgian texts processing**. Does anybody know any **stemmers**/**lemmatizers** (or other NLP tools) for Georgian that I could use with **Python**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you found help on this portal :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know any Georgian stemmer or lemmatizer. I think, however, that you have another option: to use unsupervised approaches to segment words into morphemes, and use your linguistic knowledge of Georgian to devise some heuristic rules to identify the stem among them.

This kind of approach consists of a model trained to identify morphemes without any labels (i.e. unsupervisedly). The most relevant Python package for this is [Morfessor](https://github.com/aalto-speech/morfessor). You can find its theoretical foundations in these publications: [*Unsupervised discovery of morphemes*](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W02-0603.pdf); [*Semi-supervised learning of concatenative morphology*](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W10-2210.pdf).

Also, there is a Python package called [Polyglot](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot) that offers pre-trained Morfessor models, [including one for Georgian](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MorphologicalAnalysis.html#languages-coverage). Therefore, my recommendation is for you to use Polyglot's Georgian model to segment words into morphemes and then write some rules by hand to pick the stem among them.

You should be able to evaluate the feasibility of this idea by adapting [this example from Polyglot's documentation](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MorphologicalAnalysis.html#example) from English to Georgian (by changing the language code `en` and the list of words):

```
from polyglot.text import Text, Word

words = ["preprocessing", "processor", "invaluable", "thankful", "crossed"]
for w in words:
  w = Word(w, language="en")
  print("{:<20}{}".format(w, w.morphemes))
```

Comment: Thanks @noe for the detailed answer! I think that first of all I will take your advice and try to use Polyglot in my research.

Answer (score 3):

If absolutely necessary, You could build your own stemmer. It is fairly simple programming, but takes some studying of the Georgian language in the process, there are however plenty [tutorials around the web](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-stemmer-492e9a128e84) for building a stemming process.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorials. I will use it in case of failure with the search for ready-made methods.